# Trying to Sort Two Columns

Tags: google-sheets

Realized I screwed up in initial question.  I'd like to sort by two columns for a soccer team's home and away games so that all of their games are in continuous rows.  Mockup sheet attached below.

[Description / Demonstration of what I'd like to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aizqz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a dropdown for the teams and use the filter function.

If the drop down is in cell G1...

```
=filter(A2:E,(A2:A=G1)+(B2:B=G1))
```

This will take the data in columns A through E and return any where the value in column A is equal to the team in cell G1 and any where the value in column B is equal to the team in cell G1.

You can also perform a sort on those afterward, so if you wanted to sort the results by date it would look something like.

```
=sort(filter(A2:E,(A2:A=G1)+(B2:B=G1)),5,TRUE)
```

This takes the filter result and sorts by the 5th column in ascending order (so it would show the games in the order of the date).

(Edited to match the positions of data in your example)

Sorted by Date Example
[image: Picture Example]

Showing multiple filters, you can remove the ;"","","","","" if you want, that's just so there's a break between Team A's games, Team B's games etc
[image]

Comment: Thank you Big Red.  Realize I may be over my skis since I can't quite understand your answer (which is an indictment of me not you! :)    thx again

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use a dropdown. If you are just trying to see all the games for one team you can type that team name into cell G1 and then paste the formula in my response anywhere.

Comment: Ok thx.   If I did a dropdown, would I write all the possible team names (Smith, Carson, Willams)?   And then if say "Williams" was either in the HOME or AWAY cell, then it would return "Williams"?    Oh boy, just realized that it might get confused since "Williams" and "Smith" could each be in a cell... I think my request is flawed.   thx so much for replying.

Comment: thx again Big Red.  Just saw your example to match mine.   The challenge is that I want to sort just by teams, not by date.   And have all a team's matches listed...  So it would be Team A's 10 matches (home and away) in rows 2 to 11.  Then B's 10 matches (home and away) in rows 11 to 21.  Team C's in 21 to 31.  (Then I could sort within their block by date.).    I have like 30s teams in this spreadsheet, so that's why I'm trying to automate it and do it this way.  Then  each team can see their 10 games right in order and enter them into game changer.   thx again!

Comment: You can use just the filter without the sort and have multiple of them.

Comment: I added a second picture showing what you're describing (I added a blank row in between each team which you wouldn't have to do).

Comment: That is genius Big Red.   Would you mind pasting that formula in the comments so I can vacuum it up?!   That's perfect!

Comment: Also, if there's a way to PM me, please do so I can buy you a Starbucks somehow.

Comment: ={filter(A2:E,(A2:A="Team A")+(B2:B="Team A"));"","","","","";filter(A2:E,(A2:A="Team B")+(B2:B="Team B"));"","","","","";filter(A2:E,(A2:A="Team C")+(B2:B="Team C"))}                            Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

Following your edit

```
=QUERY(A1:B9,"where A ends with 'Bane' 
              OR B ends with 'Bane'",1)
```

[image]

---

**Original answer**
Try the following

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(S1:S4,"-(\D+$)")))
```

*(**Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

Comment: I realized I didn't ask my question correctly.   And that I actually had a flaw in my thinking...

Comment: Thanks again. I just edited this question to better illustrate what I'm trying to do.  Your answer revealed my flawed thinking.  So thanks for that! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=let(z,unique(tocol({A2:A,B2:B},1)),
     reduce({"Home","Away","Date"},sequence(counta(z)),lambda(a,c,{a;filter({A2:B,E2:E},(A2:A=index(z,c))+(B2:B=index(z,c)));{"","","";"","",""}})))
```

[image]